# Exposing React On Rails Javascript to the Client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I have a Rails app which uses React On Rails so that React Components are supported and so there is a 'client' folder in my project which contains all of the associated React files such as package.json, the jsx components, and even a js folder which contains es6 javascript files that are used only by the React components.

The problem is, I have a couple of javascript files which contain helper functions that I want to be able to use both in the React components and in my Rails frontend pages.  Is there a way to specify that a javascript file is to be shared by both environments?  Right now i have the two totally separate 'js' folders; one in client and the normal rails one in  /app/assets but ideally I would like to have a shared one as well so im not copy and pasting identical js files into both - a maintenance nightmare

Comment: You can add the folders to the rails assets pipeline if you want to be able include them in your `application.js` Sprockets manifest. `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('client', 'somefolder').`.

Comment: This is a wonderful idea! I think in base rails this would work but I am using webpack for asset bundling so that is part of my confusion.  I did already add this to my application.rb before and it didnt work:

`  config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("client", "app", "assets", "javascripts")`

So I think another part of the puzzle is all of my assets are being served to my frontend in two files called app-bundle.js and vendor-bundle.js on port 3500.  I think this is a react on rails paradigm.  How can I get my javascripts in client/app/assets/javascripts to be included in those?

Comment: Okay I think we are on to something here! All I had to do was add that "config.assets.path <<  " line to my application.rb and then add the name of the file in my application_non_webpack.js with "//= require name_of_file " and now the script code is included in my app-bundle.js to the client! The one last issue is the script is in es6 and (maybe thats the reason?) but the output compiled code has a lot of "\n"s in it and doesn't actually work; the functions cant be called.  Would i need to use babel properly or something here ?

Comment: There is a ES6 tranpiler for Sprockets. I have not used it though but you should be able to find it with a little googling. I believe its Babel